# Downgrade SQLServer CE database

Tags: database, visual-studio, sql-server-ce, downgrade

I have a SQL Server CE database I am developing with and would like to downgrade the version so that 2005 Management Studio will open it. Currently, I have to use VS 2010 to open it, but it is a real pain to use that way.

I know I could install the 2008 version of SSMS, but the machine I use has serious problems with all installs. There is something messed up and I don't want to reimage the machine. So 2008 is not an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I have found is to get a tool to convert the tables into raw sql. Then use this sql against a empty DB created in a earlier CE version.